# remove required validation on input field (if I entered some text in another input field)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

remove required validation on input field (if I entered some text in another input field) .I created input fields (two input field )from json .Initially both are required.But if user enter "hello" in first field I want to remove required check from second input field.I used `watch` and onchange I checked the value of first field .but how to remove required ?I tried by using unregister but still not working

```
const onChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    if (e.target.name == "agencyName") {
      if (agencyName == "hello") {
        //remove required
        unregister({ required: false, name: "contactPerson" });
      }
    }
  };
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-watch-unir2

API link

https://react-hook-form.com/api/

Comment: Can you watch() the field 'contactPerson', then unregister(contactPerson) or unregister(contactPerson.required)?

Comment: yes I can watch `contactPerson ` but how I will unregistered ?

Comment: But what if the user subsequently deletes "hello" from the agency field? You need logic to reinstate `required` on contact, all too complicated. You need a validation expression that incorporates the value of agency.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the updated script which makes the Contact Person optional when Agency Name is equal to "hello".

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-watch-j396u

Comment: I am getting resone from server..don't change json

Comment: please remove this answer

Comment: Your question was about making validation optional, which my answer provides, you're now talking about a server issue, which is outside of the scope of your original question.

Comment: My question is why you change json ..any other solution

Comment: Your code example doesn't have JSON.  The `fields` variable isn't JSON, it's a Javascript array of objects.  I had to change `value: true` to `value: isContactPersonRequired` because you want the value to be dynamic, not hardcoded to `true`.